# Clang 'ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64'

Tags: macos, clang

I'm trying to get openmp working with clang for C++. I'm on MacOS 12.04. I used home brew to install clang and libomp, however at this point I cannot even compile a simple program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int a;
  cin >> a;
  cout << a + 1 << endl;
}
```

Compilation:

```
macbook:~ redacted$ clang b.cpp 
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      std::__1::ctype<char> const& std::__1::use_facet[abi:v160006]<std::__1::ctype<char> >(std::__1::locale const&) in b-7b7300.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen[abi:v160006](char) const in b-7b7300.o
  "std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator>>(int&)", referenced from:
      _main in b-7b7300.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::put(char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl[abi:v160006]<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in b-7b7300.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::flush()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl[abi:v160006]<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in b-7b7300.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)", referenced from:
      _main in b-7b7300.o
  "std::__1::cin", referenced from:
      _main in b-7b7300.o
  "std::__1::cout", referenced from:
      _main in b-7b7300.o
  "std::__1::ctype<char>::id", referenced from:
      std::__1::ctype<char> const& std::__1::use_facet[abi:v160006]<std::__1::ctype<char> >(std::__1::locale const&) in b-7b7300.o
  "std::__1::locale::~locale()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen[abi:v160006](char) const in b-7b7300.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen[abi:v160006](char) const in b-7b7300.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang-16: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Clang version / location:

```
macbook:~ redacted$ clang -v
Homebrew clang version 16.0.6
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin
```

Could someone help me figure out what is going wrong?

Comment: Use clang++, not clang

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem too, and I tried method mentioned in [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/lopb1z/on_mac_why_does_using_clang_show_an_error_but/), and I success:)

In one word, use `c++ b.cpp` instead of `clang b.cpp`